# SQL - Procedure function

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure

Trying to create a Procedure to (Insert, Delete and, Update) values in employee_details.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` ALTER PROCEDURE `alter_employeedetails`(in employee_id int(11), employee_name VARCHAR(30), employee_join_date date, 
employee_desgination varchar(30), employee_salary bigint(20), employee_address varchar(30), 
employee_contact varchar(30), employee_email_id varchar(30)
BEGIN
IF @StatementType = 'Insert'
BEGIN
insert into employee_details values
(employee_id, employee_name, employee_join_date, employee_desgination, employee_salary, employee_address, employee_contact, employee_email_id)
END
IF @StatementType = 'Update'
BEGIN
UPDATE employee_details SET
(employee_name = @employee_name, employee_join_date = @employee_join_date, employee_designation = @employee_desgination, 
employee_salary = @employee_salary, employee_address = @employee_address, employee_contact = @employee_contact, employee_email_id = @employee_email_id)
WHERE employee_id = @employee_id
END 
else IF @StatementType = 'Delete'
BEGIN
DELETE FROM employee_details where employee_id = @employee_id
END
end
```

Comment: Every statement has to be terminated, you don't need begin end statements within if statements,every if has to have a THEN and END IF, CREATE and ALTER should not appear together.incorrectly bracketed set statement (shouldn't be any),Elseif not else if. - Please read the manual. (and you may not be setting delimiters)

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few errors in that code...

- You forgot to prefix all the parameters with the "@" symbol.
- Forgot to include "@StatementType" as a parameter.
- Update had brackets around it.
- You cannot specify int(11) (employee_id) or bigint(20)
  (salary). It's either int / bigint (you don't specify the length
  for int/bigint datatypes). And is salary correct as bigint?  MSSQL has a "money"
  datatype, or you could use decimal(8,2) or something similar. You
  might be multiplying the salary by 100 to shift the decimal place for
  all I know?
- When inserting, do you really want to insert a employee Id? This would normally be an auto-incrementing primary key
- Insert statement missing the fields you were populating. Required if using the "values" keyword like you had specified.

Hopefully this is closer to what you want.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE alter_employeedetails 
    (@StatementType as varchar(25), @employee_id int, @employee_name VARCHAR(30), @employee_join_date date, 
    @employee_designation varchar(30), @employee_salary bigint, @employee_address varchar(30), 
    @employee_contact varchar(30), @employee_email_id varchar(30)) 
AS
BEGIN
    IF @StatementType = 'Insert'
    BEGIN
        insert into employee_details 
        (employee_id, employee_name, employee_join_date, employee_designation, employee_salary, employee_address, employee_contact, employee_email_id)
        values
        (@employee_id, @employee_name, @employee_join_date, @employee_designation, @employee_salary, @employee_address, @employee_contact, @employee_email_id)
    END
    ELSE IF @StatementType = 'Update'
    BEGIN
        UPDATE employee_details 
        SET
            employee_name = @employee_name, 
            employee_join_date = @employee_join_date, 
            employee_designation = @employee_designation, 
            employee_salary = @employee_salary, 
            employee_address = @employee_address, 
            employee_contact = @employee_contact, 
            employee_email_id = @employee_email_id
        WHERE employee_id = @employee_id
    END 
    ELSE IF @StatementType = 'Delete'
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM employee_details where employee_id = @employee_id
    END
END
```

Comment: The question is tagged 'mysql' but you seem to be answering as if it's Microsoft SQL Server. MySQL does not use the `@` sigil before procedure parameters.

Comment: Fair point - I didn't see the MySql tag! Hopefully Shreya can put his MySql knowledge together with my answer and get something working.